# remove particular xml tag using xsl

Tags: xml, xslt

I need to remove the tag `<a>` if  `href` starts  with "rem:". The text between the tag `<a>` must be show as normal text and without the link.

For input

```
<a alt="" title="" target="" class="" href="rem:6780;">prova prova< /a>
```

must be written as

```
prova prova
```

I tried this code

```
<xsl:variable name=text>
<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="string(//doc/a) contains 'rem:' ">
   <xsl: value-of ''>
  </xsl:when>
</xsl:choose>
```

Comment: Do a search on SO for the identity template. If you aren't able to figure out how to use it in your specific case then you can update your question by showing us **what you have tried and why it didn't work**. You typically won't get an answer if you don't at least show that you have tried something yourself.

Comment: you are right, I added the cose.

Comment: -1 @Marc that isn't even valid XSLT. XSLT is a tough language to learn, but if it at least validates (which most good editors will tell you) you know its close to "functional".

Answer (score 3):

Write a template

```
<xsl:template match="a[starts-with(@href, 'rem:')]">
  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>
```

Then you only need

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
   <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
   </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

and if other nodes need special treatment you add templates for them.